# jqGrid: How to load only rows that an attribute is set to true

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JSON Object as the following:

```
{
  "rows": [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": "Peter",
    "hasData": true,
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "Tom",
    "hasData": false,
  }]
}
```

And I want the jqGrid to load only rows that have data, meaning when `"hasData" == true`.

I am firstly wondering what is the best way to do such and secondly wondering how to do it.

UPDATE:
I have tried the following:

```
gridComplete: function(){
  var rowObjects = this.p.data;
    for(var i = 0; i<rowObjects.length;i++){
      if(rowObjects[i].hasData == false){
        $(this).jqGrid('delRowData',rowObjects[i].id);
      }
    }
  },
```

but the problem is when I go to the next page, all the data is loaded new from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you load the data from the server using `datatype: "json"` in combination with `loadonce: true` option. The solution is very easy if you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid. Free jqGrid allows to sort and to filter the data, returned from the server, *before* displaying the first page of data. One need to add `forceClientSorting: true` to force the applying the actions by jqGrid and `postData.filters` with the filter, which you need, and the option `search: true` to apply the filter:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
        // the filters property is the filter, which need be applied
        // to the data loaded from the server
        filters: JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "AND",
            groups: [],
            rules: [{field: "hasData", op: "eq", data: "true"}]
        })
    },
    loadonce: true,
    forceClientSorting: true,
    search: true,
    // to be able to use "hasData" property in the filter one has to
    // include "hasData" column in colModel or in additionalProperties
    additionalProperties: ["hasData"],
    ...
});
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/epcz4ptq/, which demonstrate it. The demo uses [Echo service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json) of JSFiddle to simulate server response.

Comment: For some reason the "hasData" property does not want to read the containing value. When filters is applied it just flies over the value as if it didn't exist.
Additionally at least for me, initializing the filters.rules gives me a TypeError, which I easily solved by placing it in the filters.groups

Comment: @lynxidngo: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use currently? Where is your code, which makes the problem? Sorry, but I posted the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/epcz4ptq/ in my answer. Do the demo work correctly? If you write that you have some problems, then you could modify my demo with your code, save it and post the URL of modified version.

Comment: I am using "jqGrid  5.2.1". The demo works fine. I don't know how much sense it would make to paste my code, since it is about 800 lines long.

Comment: @lynxidngo: I wrote that my answer shows how one can implement your requirements in case of usage **free jqGrid fork of jqGrid**, which I develop. The feature, which I described, exists only in free jqGrid. Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.1 is **commercial** version available under the prices found [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). It's your choice, which version to use. I asked you to post the code as response on your previous comment, where you wrote about some errors.

Comment: I figured out my error. The issue is the JSON object that I am receiving from the server. One of the properties is interacting with the other properties in such a way, that everything after it is ignored.

Comment: @lynxidngo: If you want that I help you that you should post more details, for example an example of JSON data, which reproduces a problem. You can get my demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/epcz4ptq/ and replace the value  of `myServerResponse` variable, Click on "Update" and to send me new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you another solution (in case you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net)) , which can be used with any datatype and any settings. The idea is to use beforeProcessing  event to filter the needed data.

For this purpose we assume that the data is like described from you. Here is the code:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
...
        beforeProcessing : function (data, st, xhr) {

            var test= data.rows.filter(function (row) {
                if(row.hasData == true ) { // true is not needed but for demo
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            data.rows = test;
            return true;
        }
...
});
```

I suppose the script will work in free jqGrid in case  you use them

Comment: Tried out your method, and works great for the first page. But (fyi the json object is only an example, because the real json contain more than 1000 objects) when going to the next page, it gets stuck at loading and never processes the load.

Comment: Can you please post your full data from server? You can use console.log to see the data which comes from the server and how is processed.